# Need form to have correct options available on page load

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, html

I'm developing a form in my rails app. There's an issue when using a hide/show feature. Right now it's set to show the appropriate text boxes :onchange. How do I make the appropriate text boxes show on view page load? If there is a parameter for category, say Other, and the user loads into the form. The Other options do not load with it. They would have to click something else, and click Other again for the text boxes to load.

**application.css**

```
function showMe(e) {
var strdisplay = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
var e = document.getElementById("Other");
var x = document.getElementById("Pcba");

if(strdisplay != "Other") {
    e.style.display = "none";
} else {
    e.style.display = "block";
}
if(strdisplay != "PCBA") {
    x.style.display = "none";
} else {
    x.style.display = "block";
}
```

}

**VIEW**

```
<div class="form-group">
              <label>Category</label>
              <%= f.select(:category, [["Select...","Select..."],["PCBA","PCBA"], ["Other","Other"]], {}, { :class => 'form-control', :onchange => "showMe(this)", :onload => "showMe(this)", :default => 'Select...'})%>
            </div>
              <div class="form-group" id="Other" style="display: none">
                    <label>Quantity</label>
                    <%= f.number_field :quantity, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter Quantity", required: true  %>
              </div>

                <div id="Pcba" class="form-group" style="display: none">
                  <label>Serial Number</label>
                  <%= f.text_field :serial, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter Serial", required: true %>
                  <br>
                  <label>Software Revisions</label>
                  <%= f.text_field :serial, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter Serial", required: true %>
                </div>
```

Comment: Did you try calling your function on page load?

Comment: ya, tried that but same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a console.log to your showMe function to confirm that it was not being called when the page loaded (if you don't use the console to debug, it's super helpful!).  I don't believe the onload on your select was doing anything.

This is the code I whipped up to test how to fix your issue:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function showMe(e) {
        console.log('showMe called');
        var strdisplay = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        var e = document.getElementById("Other");
        var x = document.getElementById("Pcba");

        if(strdisplay != "Other") {
          e.style.display = "none";
        } else {
          e.style.display = "block";
        }
        if(strdisplay != "PCBA") {
          x.style.display = "none";
        } else {
          x.style.display = "block";
        }
      }
      window.onload = function() {
        showMe(document.getElementById('category'));
      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Category</label>
        <select id="category" onchange="showMe(this)" onload="showMe(this)">
          <option>Select...</option>
          <option selected>PCBA</option>
          <option>Other</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" id="Other" style="display: none">
        <label>Quantity</label>
        <input id="quantity" />
      </div>
      <div id="Pcba" class="form-group" style="display: none">
        <label>Serial Number</label>
        <input id="serial" />
        <br>
        <label>Software Revisions</label>
        <input id="serial" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm using window.onload to call your showMe function when the page loads.  Since it is expecting to be passed your select element, I'm using document.getElementById to get the element and pass it in to the showMe function.  You can do both of these with jQuery as well.

Let me know if it works!